# WCF/Silverlight: Why use a ChannelFactory instead of a Client?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

In inherited a project that uses a ChannelFactory instead of a Client for WCF calls. Why would you do that?

Also, is it safe to cache the result of a ChannelFactory.CreateChannel() call or should you create a new one each time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the WCF client is a two-step process:

- creating the channel factory
- using that channel factory, create the actual channel

Step 1 is rather expensive in terms of processing power and speed - so if you can create the channel factory and then cache is somewhere, you can save yourself a bit of resources and create a channel off that cached channel factory will be faster than re-creating the whole client all the time.

So in this setup, I would try to cache the `ChannelFactory`, if you can - and re-create the channel from that factory every time you need it.

Comment: But why would they cache the Channel itself? And is there any danger in doing so?

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: well, if you can cache and reuse a channel, then you don't need to do any of the two steps - at least as long as the channel doesn't stumble into "faulted" mode (when an exception has happened). The danger is that you must almost check before every use that a cached Channel isn't in the faulted state - if it is, you need to re-create it.

Comment: Is there a way for me to explicitly cause it to fault? I would like to demonstrate that to my colleagues.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: sure - lots of ways: specify an invalid service address, or have a really really short sendTimeout (00:00:01), or call a service method that throws a .NET exception (NotImplementedException or something)

Comment: I'm not so sure that is true. I get expections and timeouts all the time but it doesn't seem to foul the channel.

Comment: @Jonathan Allen: OK, true - the client-only execptions will probably not fault the channel - but if you have a "bad" method on your service that will throw (and not catch) a .NET exception, that for sure will fault the channel!

Comment: I found out elsewhere the reason I'm not fouling the channel is that I'm using a connetionless endpoint.